# How to connect nginx frontend to aspnetcore backend on k8s?

Tags: nginx, service, kubernetes, frontend, backend

how are you?, i´m having trouble with the connection between my frontend and backend deployments in kubernetes. Inside of my Nginx frontend I can:

`curl http://abphost`

But in the browser I'm getting:

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

- abphost is a ClusterIP service.
- I´m using a NodePort service to access my nginx frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in the browser I'm getting:

Sure, that's because the cluster has its own DNS server, called [kube-dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) that is designed to resolve things *inside* the cluster that would not ordinarily have any meaning whatsoever *outside* the cluster.

It is an improper expectation to think that `http://my-service.my-ns.svc.cluster.local` will work anywhere that doesn't have `kube-dns`'s `Servce` IP as its DNS resolver.

If you want to access the backend service, there are two tricks to do that: create a 2nd `Service` of `type: NodePort` that points to the backend, and the point your browser at that new `NodePort`'s port, or

By far the more reasonable and scalable solution is to use an [Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/nginx-0.12.0#readme) to surface as many `Service`s as you wish, using the same nginx virtual-hosting that you are likely already familiar with using. That way you only expend *one* `NodePort` but can expose almost infinite `Services`, and have very, very fine grained control over the manner in which those `Service`s are exposed -- something much harder to do using *just* `type: NodePort`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, this helps me a lot. I resolved it creating a 2nd service of type NodePort!